# Handle the response of a submit from within evaluate()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to scrape a page and am running into a problem. Here's the basic user steps it's executing;

1. load login page (using page.open)
2. enter credentials (using page.evaluate from within the callback passed to open)
3. submit the form (also in the page.evaluate)

When I do the user steps in my browser the POST request made from submitting the form comes back with a couple set-cookies in the headers, these cookies are necessary for some subsequent requests. When PhantomJS executes these actions the cookies fail to get set as proven by;

```
page.open(loginUrl, function (status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        //evaluate account and pwd to login
        page.evaluate(function (email, password) {
            console.log("Email: " + email);
            console.log("Pass: " + password);
            document.querySelector('input[name="theAccountName"]').value = email;
            document.querySelector('input[name="theAccountPW"]').value = password;
            document.querySelector('form').submit();
            return;
        }, email, password);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < page.cookies.length; i++)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(page.cookies[i]) + "\n");
```

The above code will print 6 of 8 cookies necessary, the two it's missing are the ones returned by the submit I'm doing with evaluate. Is there anyway to access that response? Why are the cookies returned by it not being set? Is this simply a bug in PhantomJS? It seems if my workflow requires the submission of a form it doesn't correctly emulate the browser (the response is ignored/I have not access to it).

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS works just as any other browser. Cookies should be set.

Form submission requires at least a round trip to set the cookies, but `form.submit()` doesn't wait for the request to be answered. It returns immediately. When you then access `page.cookies` it simply isn't updated.

Use `setTimeout()` to wait a little before looping over `page.cookies`.

---

The WebKit engine behind PhantomJS 1.x is more than 4 years old. So it is possible that the request is dropped because of bugs or incompatibilities. You might need to update to PhantomJS 2.

To see whether there are problems register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events.

Comment: That explanation makes sense to me, however I'd previously seen a similar one and even if I check my cookies 30 seconds after the submit occurred I still am missing the two that are set by it's response.

Comment: Can you check whether they are also not listed in `phantom.cookies`?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the phantom objects set of cookies is the same as the page objects.

Comment: Did the event handlers turn something up? You should make sure that the page is actually loaded after submit. You can register to `page.onResourceRequested` and `page.onResourceReceived`. You can also take a screenshot with `page.render()`.

Comment: I have the event handlers you mentioned plus a couple others and they turned up nothing. I'll try page.render() as well as some other code in `onResourceRecieved`